# How can I add individual dropdown buttons by jquery mobile to multiple collapsible div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, jquery-mobile

I am looking to have 3 collapsible panel, and also a drop-down button for users to change the selection that will load withing the respective panel area on my mobile web app.

I was able to add only one button, I need some help to be able to display the button on the correct div, my button 3 is displaying on the div 1.

```
<body>
  <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collapsible">
    <a href="#" class="my-delete ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-corner-all">Dropdown 1</a>
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
  </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collapsible">
    <a href="#" class="my-delete ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-corner- all">Dropdown 2</a>
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
  </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collapsible">
    <a href="#" class="my-delete ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-corner-all">Dropdown 3</a>
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also I would like to convert this button to a drop-down, and apparently that conflicts with the class when I change from:

```
    <a href="#" class="my-delete ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-corner-all">Dropdown 3</a>
```

to:

```
   <div id="myDropdown" class="my-delete dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
```

I have an example on http://jsfiddle.net/pwgdk84j/, this source can be seeing at view-source:http://fiddle.jshell.net/pwgdk84j/show/light/

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part here is where to add the button inside the collapsible markup - i'm prepend it to the collapsiblle container, by using jQuery `prependTo` to keep a reference for the click event to attach.

Please note, it's hard to guess what you mean under "dropdown", as in your example it looks just like a link button. Anyway, here is my proposal:

```js
$(document).on("collapsiblecreate", function(event){ 
  var that = $(event.target), idx = $(that).jqmData("index"), title = "Dropdown "+idx;
  var btn = '<a href="#" data-index="'+idx+'" class="ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left head-inline">'+title+'</a>';
  $(btn).prependTo(that).click(function () {
    //do your action here
    console.log($(this).jqmData("index"));
  });
});
```

```css
.head-inline {
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 2 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0 !important;
  width: 100px !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
}

.ui-collapsible-heading {
  border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 158px !important;
}

.ui-btn:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.ui-collapsible-content {
  border: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h2>Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-index="1">
        <h3>Title 1</h3>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
          <input name="rg-1" id="r-1-1" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio">
          <label for="r-1-1">One</label>
          <input name="rg-1" id="r-1-2" value="off" type="radio">
          <label for="r-1-2">Two</label>
          <input name="rg-1" id="r-1-3" value="other" type="radio">
          <label for="r-1-3">Three</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-index="2">
        <h3>Title 2</h3>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
          <input name="rg-2" id="r-2-1" value="on" checked="checked" type="radio">
          <label for="r-2-1">One</label>
          <input name="rg-2" id="r-2-2" value="off" type="radio">
          <label for="r-2-2">Two</label>
          <input name="rg-2" id="r-2-3" value="other" type="radio">
          <label for="r-2-3">Three</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h2>Footer</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For buttons and icons positioned to the right side, it is usual to set a fixed size. You should adjust it depending from your needs, in my example is set to 100px.

Moreover, as you don't have declared in your markup any page nor page content, if you need full-width collapsibles (`data-inset="false"`), you may also completely remove the margin of the button:

```
.head-inline {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to put your suggestion to work. I tried here [http://jsfiddle.net/20eoLz60/](http://jsfiddle.net/20eoLz60/) but it is not collapsing any more, and superposing.

Comment: @RicardoGuimaraes: you should include just one time the libraries you need ... http://jsfiddle.net/20eoLz60/1/

Comment: this is almost perfect. When collapsing, I need only text below. And I need to convert this button on the right hand side to a real dropdown. Can you help me with that? [http://jsfiddle.net/pfegcv2k/](http://jsfiddle.net/pfegcv2k/) I need my button exactly where it is, but to be a dropdown like that [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click)

Answer (score 0):

you have some small mistakes in your code.

first of all you display all 3 Dropdowns, but only one is visible because of the position:absolute. (they stack).

change the parent class to:

```
.my-collapsible {
  position: relative;
}
```

then you detach all your dropdowns, but write only the last on in the variable and attach it afterwards to all 3 sections.

do you want to replace only the 3rd dropdown to the link 1?

EDIT:

NO JS:

```
    <body>
  <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collapsible">
    <select>  
    <option>Dropdown 1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
  </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collapsible">
    <select>  
    <option>Dropdown 2</option>
   <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" class="my-collapsible">
     <select>  
    <option>Dropdown 3</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    </select>
    <h3>Title 3</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That helped,  now I have 3 of the same button on the right side of each div. A little out of position. But all those are the same button 3. I needed to be Title 1 Button 1, Title 2 Button 2 and Title 3 Button 3. Also, I need help to convert those to drop-down, all 3 of them I would like drop-down [http://jsfiddle.net/ghtcoq1t/](http://jsfiddle.net/ghtcoq1t/)

Comment: @RicardoGuimaraes if you remove your js its the correct 1to3 dropdown. i dont understand what should be converted. the dropdown links (on the right) should be what exactly? i updated my answer.

Comment: if I remove the js the button appears only when I open the collapsible nav bar. It has to show all the time. Please have a look at user deblocker suggestion [http://jsfiddle.net/pfegcv2k/](http://jsfiddle.net/pfegcv2k/), it is almost perfect, all I need now is to convert the right button to a dropdown such as  [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar_click)